# FatalErrorException in PostController.php line 12: Class 'App\Post' not found

Tags: laravel, hosting, web-hosting

I get this error when I try to login to the system using this link I am using this username: haa@gmail.com and this password :haa1234. what might be a problem with the server or the hosting server because in the local machine it is working fine.

`app\Http\Controllers\PostController.php`

This piece of code is correct. 
This the link to the system :

`http://entrepreneurbase.haoyetu.com`

and the login is:

`username: haa@gmail.com`

`password: haa1234`

Try those credential and you will get the error that I have described.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
//namespace routes;
use App\Post; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function getDashboard()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
        return view('dashboard', ['posts'=>$posts]);
    }
    public function postCreatePost(Request $request)
    {
        // Validation
        $this->validate($request, [
            'body' => 'required|max:1000'
            ]);
        $post = new Post();
        $post->body = $request['body'];
        $message = 'There was an error posting try again';
        if ($request->user()->posts()->save($post)) { 
            $message = 'post successfully created!';
        }
        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message' => $message]);
    }

    public function getDeletePost($post_id)
    {
        $post = Post::where('id', $post_id)->first();
        if (Auth::user() !=$post->user) {
            return redirect()->back();
        }
        $post->delete();
        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message' => 'successfully deleted!']);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your `App\Post` Model

Comment: `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
     public function user()
     {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
     } 
}` .

Comment: your namespacing is not right. first, you are using the controller twice, and the last one you don't need it. secondly, you only need to write use Auth, not the whole path. once you do that, tell us if you get any other errors. and delete this line: `//namespace routes;`

Comment: @GrowingDev in the local machine the program is working fine without any error but when i upload the files to server i get that error.when i asked the hosting company whether they support laravel framework they told me they don't support it.is there away i can done to solve that problem.

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dumpautoload` on the server?

Comment: But did you changed the .htaccess file to point to the correct path of the index.php? im guessing that this is a shared hosting server, so you need to point it to the correct direction.

Comment: the system is running in the server as subdomain `http://entrepreneurbase.haoyetu.com/public/#` .

Comment: i did not include the .htaccess because the index is in public folder so instead i configured a redirect path in the server to redirect the page when one put in the url

Comment: @jonathan  i am using a cpanel to connect to the sever .unless i try putty to access the server